# Scala: Exposing a class in another package and running into problems

Tags: scala

I have a class within a trait in one package:

```
trait NRC {
    final case class Singleton(e: TupleExpr) extends BagExpr {
       val tp: BagType = BagType(e.tp)
    }
}
```

And I want to expose it using an object in another class which I have done like so:

```
case object Exposed extends NRC {
  def apply(x: TupleExpr): BagExpr = {
    Singleton(x)
  }
}
```

Now when it comes to using this implementation I run into issues:

I am using it like so (Note that WrappedDataset is another class which extends NRC):

```
val e1: WrappedDataset = ds.wrap()
val r1 = e1.customMap(x => Singleton(x))
```

On the second line above I get a type mismatch errors:

> Type mismatch. Required: Singleton.TupleExpr, found: e1.TupleExpr

&

> Type mismatch. Required: e1.BagExpr, found: Singleton.BagExpr

Which to me doesn't really make sense as they are referring to the same thing essentially.

The errors can be fixed using casting like this:

```
val r1 = e1.flatMap(x => Singleton(x.asInstanceOf[Exposed.TupleExpr]).asInstanceOf[e1.BagExpr])
```

However this isn't an adequate solution as I need this logic to be hidden.
Is there some way to handle this in the case object Singleton, or another work around that could be possible?

Comment: not sure if my guess is correct because there are some missing parts of your code. The case class `NRC.Singleton` can't live outside NRC because it's defined inside that trait. So, if you have a class `A` and `B`, both extending `NRC`, each class will have their internal `Singleton` and can be shared between them. If that is not the case, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Don't extend traits as ways to share data type definitions

Comment: @GastónSchabas I believe you are correct in your guess - assuming you meant 'can't' be shared between them rather than 'can'

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Can you elaborate on this comment please?

Comment: @B-Brennan you are right. My bad. **can't be shared** is what I wanted to write.

Comment: @B-Brennan it looks like you are trying to use `traits` as `packages` and inheritance as a way to share access to data types. That is a bad idea and unnecessary since you can just use `imports`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call everything `Singleton`, making it pretty hard to follow and understand what you are trying to do,  there also no definition of `TupleExpr` anywhere, so I can only guess what is going on ...

But I am guessing your problem is you do not realize that inner type definitions are *instance* specific:

```
trait Foo { case class X(x: String) } 
object Bar extends Foo
object Baz extends Foo

class Bat extends Foo 

Bar.X("foo") == Baz.X("foo") // false
new Bat().X("foo") == new Bat().X("foo") // false
```

This returns `false` because not only `Bar.X` and `Baz.X` are two different classes (`Bar` and `Baz` are actually different types), but `new Bat().X` and `new Bat().X` are *also* different classes because they belong to different instances (albeit of the same type).

Comment: I have updated my question to be more definitive. This is helpful. You are right I did not know about this behaviour. So to my original question, is there a workaround possible on Expose() that can allow me to use the types interchangeably?

Comment: You cannot use them interchangeably because they are _different_ types. If you want a single type, take it out of the trait, and define it at a package level or inside of an object. Then all the dependent classes would refer to the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Beside I think the @Dima's answer is pretty clear, I would like to provide more info and details.

Looks like you are trying to use something similar to [java inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). [Scala Inner classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/inner-classes.html) works different. Also you have [traits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html) which is what you are using in this case.

> In `Scala` it is possible to let **classes have other classes as members**.
> As opposed to `Java-like` languages where such **inner classes are members
> of the enclosing class**, in `Scala` such **inner classes are bound to the
> outer object**.

You have pretty good scala examples in the docs, but I would like to add also Java code too.

---

### In Java, you can do the following

1. declare a class `A` with an inner class `InnerClass` and a static inner class `StaticInnerClass`

```java
class A {
    class InnerClass {}
    static class StaticInnerClass {}
    public void receiveInnerClass(InnerClass innerClass) {}
    public static void receiveStaticInnerClass(InnerClass staticInnerClass) {}

    public InnerClass newInnerClass() {
        return new InnerClass();
    }

    public static StaticInnerClass newStaticInnerA() {
        return new StaticInnerClass();
    }
}
```

2. In another class, you can share inner classes from two different instances of `A`

```java
A anA = new A();
A anotherA = new A();
A.InnerClass aInnerClass = anA.newInnerClass();
A.InnerClass anotherInnerClass = anotherA.newInnerClass();

anA.receiveInnerClass(aInnerClass);
anA.receiveInnerClass(anotherInnerClass);
```

---

### In Scala there are some things you can and you can't do with inner classes

There is no static classes, you have [classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html) and [Singleton Objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html).

1. We can define a class `A` with an inner class `InnerClass` and a singleton object `A` with an inner class `InnerClassFromCompanion`

```scala
class A {
  class InnerClass

  def newInnerClass: InnerClass = new InnerClass
  def receiveInnerClass(innerClass: InnerClass): Unit = ()
  def receiveInnerAFromCompanion(innerAFromCompanion: A.InnerClassFromCompanion) = ()
}

object A {
  class InnerClassFromCompanion

  def newInnerClassFromCompanion: InnerClassFromCompanion = new InnerClassFromCompanion
  def receiveInnerClassFromCompanion(innerClassFromCompanion: InnerClassFromCompanion): Unit = ()
  def receiveInnerClass(innerClass: A.InnerClass) = ()
}
```

2. from another place there will be things that can be done and some others can't

```scala
val anA: A = new A
val innerClassFromAnA: A.InnerClass = anA.newInnerClass // this won't compile because it's trying to find `InnerClass` inside singleton object `A`
val innerClassFromAnA: anA.InnerClass = anA.newInnerClass // we can notice that is typed as `anA.InnerClass`, not as an `A.InnerClass`
val anotherA: A = new A
val innerClassFromAnotherA: anotherA.InnerClass = anotherA.newInnerClass // same here about how is typed

// the following lines will fail saying typemismatch
anA.receiveInnerClass(innerClassFromAnotherA) // required `anA.InnerClass`, found `anotherA.InnerClass` 
anotherA.receiveInnerClass(innerClassFromAnA) // required `anotherA.InnerClass`, found `anA.InnerClass`
```

3. in your case, where you want to share inner classes in different classes, a way of solving that is to extract the inner class from the **trait** you have and move to a singleton object or directly not declare it as an inner class

```scala
val anInnerFromACompanionA = new A.InnerClassFromCompanion
val anotherInnerFromACompanionA = new A.InnerClassFromCompanion

A.receiveInnerClassFromCompanion(anInnerFromACompanionA)
A.receiveInnerClassFromCompanion(anotherInnerFromACompanionA)
```